# How to write Nunit test for a method which passes an object (C#)

Tags: c#, nunit

I am quite new to Nunit test and trying to figure out writing tests for a particular method. As can be seen below, I have got this method name AddorGetCustomer which takes a parameter, Order. I have attached how the Order looks like after this method.

```
public class Class : IClass
    {
        private readonly CRMEntities _db;
        private readonly IMapper _mapper;
        private readonly IService _service;

        public CustomerService(CRMEntities db, IMapper mapper, IService service)
        {
            _db = db;
            _mapper = mapper;
            _service = service;
        }

        public Data.Customer AddorGetCustomer(Order order)
        {
            if (order.BillToAddress == null) return null;
            
            var address = _mapper.Map<CustomerAddress>(order.BillToAddress);
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(address.Email)) return null;

            return AddOrGet(address, order.Branch, order.OrderNumber, order.ShipmentNumber, order.OrderDate);
        }
```

The Order that I am passing into, looks something like:

```
        public string  Name { get; set; }

        public decimal Country { get; set; }

        public Address BillToAddress { get; set; }
```

Address:

```
public class Address
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        public string LastName { get; set; }

        public string Company { get; set; }

        public string Address1 { get; set; }

        public string Address2 { get; set; }

        public string Address3 { get; set; }

        public string Address4 { get; set; }

        public string PostalCode { get; set; }

        public string CountryCode { get; set; }

        public string Phone { get; set; }

        public string Email { get; set; }
    }
```

So,

1. I want check when (order.BillToAddress is null), then my test should return null,
2. when (address.Email) is null or empty, return null. How could I do it? After hours of googling, couldnt find a way of writing test in Nunit. Any hints or suggestion would be appreciated (Keeping in mind that I am very new to Nunit)

That's what I have done so far:
1.

```
 public class CustomerServiceTests
    {
        private Mock<CRMEntities> _moqCRMEntities;
        private CustomerService _customerService;
        private IMapper _mapper;
        private Order _order;
        private Address _address;

        [SetUp]

        public void Setup()
        {
            _moqCRMEntities = new Mock<CRMEntities>();
            _address = new Address()
            {
                FirstName = "X",
                LastName = "Y",
                Company = "MW",
                Address1 = "28 Street",
                Address2 = "29 Street",
                Address3 = "5 Road",
                Address4 = "10 London Road",
                PostalCode = "IT6 U7G",
                CountryCode = "90",
                Phone = "07785365",
                Email = "XY@yahoo.com"
            };
            _order = new Order()
            {
                BillToAddress = _address
            };
            
        }

        [Test]
        public void Whe()
        {
            _customerService = new CustomerService(null, _mapper, _loyaltyServiceMock.Object);
            //Act 
            var result = _customerService.AddorGetCustomer(_order);
            //Assert
            Assert.AreEqual(_order,result);
        }
    }
```

2. [Test]
   public void EmailIsNullOrEmpty_AddorGetCustomer_ReturnsNull()
   {
   var address = new Address
   {
   FirstName = "Jerry"
   };

   ```
             var order = new Order
             {
                 Branch = "MW",
                 OrderNumber = 1,
                 BillToAddress = address
             };
             //Act 
             var result = _customerService.AddorGetCustomer(order);
             //Assert
             Assert.Null(result);
         }
   ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    [Test]
    public void AddorGetCustomer_When_Order_BillToAddressIsNull_ReturnsNull()
    {
        var order = new Order
        {
            Name = "foo",
            Country = 1m;
            BillToAddress = null
        }

        _customerService = new CustomerService(null, _mapper, _loyaltyServiceMock.Object);

        //Act 
        var result = _customerService.AddorGetCustomer(order);

        //Assert
        Assert.Null(result);
    }
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your reply. But it is giving me this error: System.NullReferenceException : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: Maybe the `_loyaltyServiceMock` is null and throwing? I can only go by what you give me.

Comment: Is the `_loyaltyServiceMock` being instantiated?

Comment: It wasnt. Just instantiated _loyaltyServiceMock. It worked. Thanks a lot

Comment: Is it possible to give some hints for the second part please? I have tried to follow what you have done for the first part. But for second part I am getting the same error:  System.NullReferenceException : Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Comment: I would assume that it is likely your `_mapper` has not been instantiated. If you are using `Moq`, then you can just mock the `IMapper` to return what you want:
`var customerAddress = new CustomerAddress{ set whatever properties you want mapper to return };
var mapper = new Mock<IMapper>();
mapper.Setup(x => x.Map<Address>(It.IsAny<Address>())).Returns(customerAddress);`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249747/discussion-between-tom-and-digital-jedi).